# Create new object Program and related objects Segments using data from another database and user provided fields

Tags: django

I am reading entries from an outside database using get_context_data and displaying them in a list. When user choses an entry - you get a form which displays the chosen entry's data via context.

I want to create a model object based on what the user entered, and also create the related object(s) using the context data displayed on the form (not editable information).

For example:

```
   You have a list of shows from the last month:
      Show-Dec-31
      Show-Dec-30
      Show-Dec-29
          .
          .
      Show-Dec-1

When you choose a show (say Show-Dec-25):
    You get a form with
       Name:   Show-Dec-25   - User can change this if they want
     Producer:  _______          (required)      
     Editor:    ________         (required)
    Air Time:   __:__:__         (required)
    Run Time:   __:__:__         (required)

Segments: (via context)          (Display only)
   1  Intro        00:01:00                
   2  Monologue    00:01:00
   3  Dance Skit   00:09:00
   4  Comedy Skit  00:09:00

  Create Button Here
```

When the user hits create - it creates a new Program in form_valid by
saying:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    new_program = Program()
    new_program.title = form.name
    new_program.producer = form.producer 
    new_program.editor  = form.editor
    new_program.air_time= form.air_time
    new_program.run_time= form.run_time
    new_program.save()
```

The segments need to be created - based off of the just created new_program id.
So if new_program id after creation was 44 - then
it would create four segment objects - with program ID of 44. The foreign Key in Segments is program id.
If I am correct - the new_program.pk is the newly created id, so after the save I can use that.  What I am unsure about is how to get the context entries for the segments into the valid_form function, so that I can create new segment objects for each chunk of the show. They are displaying just fine in the template.  Is this the right direction to be going using the form_valid function?
I was thinking I could say:

```
   for segs in context_segments:
     new_seg = Segment()
     new_seg.program = new_program.pk
     new_seg.count   = segs.count
     new_seg.title   = segs.title
     new_seg.runtime = segs.run_time
     new_seg.save()
```

How do I get context_segments into the form_valid function?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by making a new object for the model I needed. Had to override the form_valid, create new object(s) and save them using the context I passed into it (get_context_data - returns the context data). Also had to make sure it redirected to the next page I wanted - If returned a super(form_Create.self). form_valid(form) it would create 2 entries in the model because I already saved the object.